# Group multi dimensional array according to title field and display the sum of all the rows with the same title (item)

Tags: php

I have this multi dimensional array of sales transactions, that I get from an API, so no database access. Some transactions have the same product as another transaction:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 1,
    'product_title' => 'Product 1',
    'selling_price' => 50.0,
    'quantity' => 1,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => 2,
    'product_title' => 'Product 2',
    'selling_price' => 80.0,
    'quantity' => 2,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => 3,
    'product_title' => 'Product 1',
    'selling_price' => 50.0,
    'quantity' => 8,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'id' => 4,
    'product_title' => 'Product 4',
    'selling_price' => 120.0,
    'quantity' => 3,
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'id' => 5,
    'product_title' => 'Product 2',
    'selling_price' => 80.0,
    'quantity' => 3,
  ),
)
```

I need to display the items according to title and then the products with the highest revenue (quantity * selling_price) displayed descending order.

I've got this and then I get just the title of each product:

```
$results = array();
foreach ($sales as $key => $value) {
    $results[$value['product_title']] = $value[0];
}
echo "<table>";
foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $key . "</td></tr>";
};
echo "</table>";
```

But I want the title and the revenue(quantity * selling_price) with the product with the highest revenue at the top.

Comment: What is `$value[0]` supposed to access? None of your sub-arrays has any item with that key.

Comment: `$results[$value['product_title']] = ...` - you are overwriting the entry in results here each time the product title is the same. This line should be `$results[$value['product_title']][] = $value;`, so that you got all your data actually grouped under the product title first.

Comment: Ok thank you for clearing that up and I corrected it. Still need to get the revenue displayed and sorted but I appreciate the correction.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Want to sort first by product_title then by revenue? Or just by DESC revenue?

Comment: No just want to sort by revenue. So group by title but sort by revenue desc

Comment: Hum... "sort by revenue. So group by title"? Can you give us the expected result according to your example array?

Comment: Is this the expected result?
Product 1 / 400
Product 4 / 360
Product 2 / 240
Product 2 / 160
Product 1 / 50

Comment: No products with the same title should only display once so the correct result will be Product 1 - $450
Product 2 - $400
Product 4 - $360

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution with php7 and more, with:

```
$input = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 1,
    'product_title' => 'Product 1',
    'selling_price' => 50.0,
    'quantity' => 1,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => 2,
    'product_title' => 'Product 2',
    'selling_price' => 80.0,
    'quantity' => 2,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => 3,
    'product_title' => 'Product 1',
    'selling_price' => 50.0,
    'quantity' => 8,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'id' => 4,
    'product_title' => 'Product 4',
    'selling_price' => 120.0,
    'quantity' => 3,
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'id' => 5,
    'product_title' => 'Product 2',
    'selling_price' => 80.0,
    'quantity' => 3,
  ),
);
```

Group and sum:

```
foreach($input as $row){
  $sum[$row['product_title']] ??= 0;
  $sum[$row['product_title']] += $row['selling_price']*$row['quantity'];
}
```

And finaly DESC ordering:

```
arsort($sum);
//var_export($sum);
foreach($sum as $key => $value) {
    echo $key .' / '.$value . PHP_EOL ;
}
```

Results:

```
Product 1 / 450
Product 2 / 400
Product 4 / 360
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try it and let you know. Could you just tell me what this line means with the two question marks pls? $sum[$row['product_title']] ??= 0; Still learning and have not seen that before.

Comment: Good luck :) this is just null coalescing assignment in PHP 7.4. So it's basically just a shorthand to assign a value if it hasn't been assigned before.

Comment: I see thanks so much for the explanation. Slowly but surely up the hill I go lol

Comment: Works perfectly thank you, but now I have another problem. The records are only given to you 100 at a time and there are multiple pages (8 to be exact) so how do I traverse the other pages? I suppose I should ask that in another question. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Glad it works! If my answer suits you, don't forget to mark it as solved and to vote if it seems useful to you (click up arrow) please. And, yes, for clarity, post another question. Thanks.

Comment: Ok thanks and I will post another question.